# Statistics in PieCloudDB Database

Tags: statistics

When using PieCloudDB Database, I noticed that some tables have data loading every day. Recently, when I checked the execution plan, I found that the statistics of some tables are consistently accurate, while the statistics of other tables are always incorrect. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the tables with inaccurate statistics have experienced data deletion operations in the past. Currently, PieCloudDB Database's automatic statistics collection can accurately capture changes in data loading, but if there is data deletion, there may be differences in the statistics.

You can use the 'analyze' command to actively collect statistics information. During daily operations, you can ignore the data loading operations. However, for data deletion operations, especially those involving a large amount of data, it is recommended to follow up with an 'analyze' command to collect statistics information.